# How can I toggle a UITabBarController's button destination between two ViewControllers

Tags: ios5, xcode4.2

I'm a bit stumped with this one...

Consider this app:

[image]

The app has a tab bar navigation at the bottom with buttons **recipes**, **favourites** and **settings**

Recipes can be shown in two ways - either as a list, or as an grid of images.

The user can toggle between the list and grid views by pressing the toggle button and the app should remember the previous setting.

So...

- I boot the app and press the **Recipes** button.
- I'm looking at the recipes as a list and I press toggle
- The screen flips (via UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal) and now I can see the recipes arranged as a grid.
- I press **settings** to change some settings.
- When I press **Recipes** again the recipes should *still* be listed as a grid.
- When I press the toggle button, the recipes are shown as a list again etc.

## The Problem...

Assuming the list view is the default, how do I tell the newly instantiated grid view that it should use the same TabBar as the list view?

How can I make this transition look seamless?

I understand that I shouldn't use one controller for multiple views, or one view across multiple controllers... Should I use a separate view/controller for each screen here or use the same and show/hide subviews as required?

All advice appreciated

Answer (score 0):

You need two separate ViewControllers for both screens.

If you want to make it as you show, take Xcode template called "Utility application" as a base.

I believe better to use here UITabBarController.

I recommend you also to read Human Interface Guidelines from Apple.